# Use Logrotate to truncate log files after every entry or clear last 'n' entries

Tags: linux, bash, logging, logrotate

i have created a logrotate config file:

```
touch /etc/logrotate.d/.test
```

with the conficurations:

```
/home/myUser/test*.log{
    size 0
    hourly
    rotate 0    
    nocreate
    nocompress
    missingok
    nocopytruncate
    ifempty
}
```

I want to be able to clear the files after every entry (block log file) or in some log files to clear the last 'n' entries. Actualy, i want to keep doing:

```
truncate -s 0 /home/myUser/test*.log
```

As it is, `nocopytruncate` delete's the log files. If i put `copytruncate` it creates a second log of each log "test*.log.1", ignoring `rotate 0`. 
 If i excecute the commands bellow doesn't do anything, ignoring `size 0`.

```
echo "hello" >> ~/test1.log
cat ~/test1.log
  //output: hello
```

Feels like it doesn't work by using `size`. For this to work, I need to excecute :

```
logrotate -f .test
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Is it possible to do this by using logrotate and keep the config file hidden somehow (as it is) ?

As for the 2nd part to clear last 'n' enries, I have no idea how can i do this with logrotate.

Comment: It won't work.    Turn off logging in your app to send it to > /dev/null.   logrotate isn't designed like this.  It runs periodically so logs will still be written.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? I'm intreasting to do this even on common applications like apache, mysql e.t.c By clearing even every log in the system.

Comment: Why? If the end result is the same as not writing the logs in the first place, just don't write the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using logrotate.

I'd just do something like this:

```
ln -s /dev/null /home/myUser/test.log
```

Which will cause all logging data to go to the null device.

But logging is useful and normally you shouldn't just throw it away.  Most apps allow you to modify how much they log and where they log to.  I'd use those methods before just throwing them away.

Comment: Imagine this to do it in `/var/log/*.log` . I think that this will cause a mesh.

Comment: It'd be helpful to understand why you want to turf all your logs away.  Is it an embedded device?  it's usually easier to instruct apps not to log.

Comment: If this is not possible with logrotate, maybe crontab with truncate? Not sure.

Comment: You'd need to be a root user to logrotate /var/log for starters.  And there is so much more you'd have to hide than just logfiles.  In terms of turfing away original log files and preventing logging events from appearing I've answered that.  You need a new question.

Comment: If i excecute the command `ln -s /dev/null /var/log/*log` , can i restore this later?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will fit your project, but... have you thought of using `rotatelogs` tool from apache httpd project?

Basically, you just send output to stdout and then pipe it to rotatelogs. It will nicely organize your logs in a folder, and you can have it rotated after the logfile exceed a certain threshold.

You can read something more here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html